# How to multiply a vector 3 times to get a 3 dimentional matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a vector `B = [1; 2; 3]`. Then

```
B*B' = [1*1 1*2 1*3 ; 2*1 2*2 2*3 ; 3*1 3*2 3*3]
```

Now, I need to multiply the new matrix `B*B'` again with `B`, in order to get the following 3 dimensional matrix `C`:

```
C(:,:,1) = [1*1*1 1*2*1 1*3*1 ; 2*1*1 2*2*1 2*3*1 ; 3*1*1 3*2*1 3*3*1]

C(:,:,2) = [1*1*2 1*2*2 1*3*2 ; 2*1*2 2*2*2 2*3*2 ; 3*1*2 3*2*2 3*3*2]

C(:,:,3) = [1*1*3 1*2*3 1*3*3 ; 2*1*3 2*2*3 2*3*3 ; 3*1*3 3*2*3 3*3*3]
```

Any ideas how can I do that?

(My original vector is long so I can not do this manually..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before R2016b:

```
C = bsxfun(@times, permute(B, [3 2 1]), B*B');
```

After R2016b:

```
C = permute(B, [3 2 1]) .* (B*B');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bsxfun` to perform these operations.

```
out = bsxfun(@times, bsxfun(@times, B, B.'), reshape(B, 1, 1, []));
```

Or if you want to make it more legible, you can break it out into two operations. First perform the first multiplication.

```
tmp = bsxfun(@times, B, B.');
```

Then multiply this by `B` again (but we reshape `B` to be `1 x 1 x 3` to make the result a 3D matrix)

```
out = bsxfun(@times, reshape(B, 1, 1, []));
```

If you're on R2016b or later, you can just do the following.

```
out = (B .* B.') .* reshape(B, 1, 1, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another form is to reshape the result of the first matrix multiplication into a column, perform a second matrix multiplication, and reshape the result:

```
C = reshape(B*reshape(B*B.',1,[]),numel(B)*[1 1 1]);
```